FAQs related to Bitcoin mining and energy
Can we create a megathread kind of question in which answers cover all the FAQs related to bitcoin mining and energy?
Similar to link mentioned in https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/967/
Reason: I expect 2 genuine questions and 8 concern trolling in 10 questions related to mining and energy.
